# Future or present in this example

Tags: future-constructions

> There might be other things you are interested in.

Why is it not *you will be interested*, in the future and not in the present present as it is not sure.
Is it because ***might*** already means that it is not sure?

Comment: because will would be imposing it on you.

Comment: Other things might exist (now) of the kind that you are interested in.

Comment: It sounds like an invitation to check a list of things, so you buy everything you are interested in and not just the one thing you came to buy.

Comment: As it is not sure could we use would

Comment: If you edit your question to include the full context, someone could answer with confidence. Please also include why you think it should be in the future. On its surface, it's referring to things that person is interested in now, which is a natural thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be; but *are* is more natural.

Because of that, you would only use *will be* to indicate that something is likely to change. So

> When you've finished your degree there might be other things you will be interested in.

suggests that something will have changed (in you, or in the world) by the time you've done your degree, to give you these other interests

Whereas

> When you've finished your degree there might be other things you are interested in.

does not have this implication: it might be something that has changed, or it might the things that are there already.